# Validation using OR condition vs in_array in php

Tags: php, html

I have this validation for gender, I use the OR condition because it will only test 2 condition if male or female but I can't figure out why it throws the error in the OR condition but if `in_array` was used it works just fine, here is the code:

```
// If OR condition was used display, is Not a valid gender
<?php
if(empty($_POST['gender']))
{
   $genderError = "*Gender is required";
}

else
{
   $gender = $_POST['gender'];

   if ($gender != 'Male' || $gender != 'Female')
     $genderError = "Not a valid gender";
}
?>

// Using in_array works fine
<?php
if(empty($_POST['gender']))
{
   $genderError = "*Gender is required";
}

else
{
   $gender = $_POST['gender'];
   $genderArray = array('Male', 'Female');

   if (!inarray($gender,$genderArray))
     $genderError = "Not a valid gender";
}
?>

<input type="radio" name="gender" checked value="Male">Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `&&` instead of `||` operation because if `$gender` has value `Male` then it will satisfy your second criteria that is `$gender != 'Female'` clause and shows error.

```
if ($gender != 'Male' && $gender != 'Female'){
 // some other value, throw error
}
```

For simplicity i would go with `in_array` approach

Comment: I didn't see that coming that it needs only to be && condition. Thank you very much!